# Android 12: Using SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission to get/show data at specific time are safe in Google Play Policy?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, scheduler, android-alarms, android-workmanager

I have an Android app on Play store for 8 years. Recently Google release Android S or 12 introduce some limit with **Foreground service launch restrictions**

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#foreground-service-launch-restrictions

and
**Exact alarm permission**

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exact-alarm-permission

In the app I use foreground service and alarm clock to schedule update weather data from the cloud and device sensor and send notification to user, update the widget.
But they said: ***Exact alarms should only be used for user-facing features*** so if I continue use those API, it is safe (with Google Play policy)?

I ask this because other solution like sticky notification with foreground service and workmanager not work as my requirements.

Comment: I update for anyone search this: Google update a policy about Exact Alarm API here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/13161072. If you still want to use, using android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM and request the user on Android 14+.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

if you are testing android 12 then don't forget to add this line to Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

Update:

Android 13 generated a security exception and solution was to add below two lines in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

Update for Android 14 :

crash for users on Android 14 because the permission is no longer granted by default. This means a runtime check should be done and if not granted then you should grant it programatically

Comment: Are you saying that `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />` is necessary to add in addition to `...SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` on Android 13(+)?

Comment: Yes, and this was a solution for a security exception in Android 13.

Comment: Just to make things clear this is not correct answer. Yes USE_EXACT_ALARM works but only if your app can be categorized as "Calendar and alarm clock app" so if your app is not that and you declare this permission in your manifest it wont be approved in Google Play for example and its also not good solution. Good developer cant do that in this way. Correct answer is from @Adelino. Best regards.

Comment: This is no longer allowed for OS 14, as the app will be rejected by playstore

Answer (score 30):

Yes, the **android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM** it's safe to use, on Android 12 this permission is automatically granted by the Android system but on Android 13 you need to check if the user has granted this permission.

So you need to add the permission to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
```

And then you need to check if the permission was granted, if not granted then you need to redirect the user to the Alarms & Reminders page

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    val alarmManager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(context, AlarmManager::class.java)
    if (alarmManager?.canScheduleExactAlarms() == false) {
        Intent().also { intent ->
            intent.action = Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Google also suggests that you need to check any changes on this permission by registering a Broadcast Receiver and check the changes on **ACTION_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION_STATE_CHANGED**

Comment: You're slightly wrong, on Android 12 `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` permission automatically granted by the system, but can be revoked by the system or user anytime. Check the docs https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#using-schedule-exact-permission

Comment: @TimurPanzhiev please check what I said in the bottom part, by checking the flag ACTION_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION_STATE_CHANGED you can handle the revoked action and react to it. By default after a fresh install on Android 12 this permission is granted, them you need to handle the changes of this permission like always, but by default its granted.

Comment: I upvote this solution because some vendors don't grant these permissions autiomatically so it may help developer to handle this case gracefully.

Comment: Yes this is correct answer. If app targets Android 14+ (API level 34+) developer need to use this kid of flow to make sure app can schedule exact alarms without need to declare. USE_EXACT_ALARM permission which should be used only for calendar and alarm only apps (main functionality). Accepted answer of this question is not correct and this answer should be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the official documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#USE_EXACT_ALARM):

> If your app is already using SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM on older SDKs but
> needs **USE_EXACT_ALARM** on SDK 33 and above, then SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM
> should be declared with a **max-sdk attribute**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

The doc also warns:

> **This is only intended for use by apps that rely on exact alarms for
> their core functionality**
>
> [...]
>
> Keep in mind that this is a powerful permission and app stores may enforce policies to audit and review the use of this permission. Such audits may involve **removal** from the app store **if** the app is found to be **misusing** this permission.

The exact alarm should be used only if you are using any `set*exact*` method to trigger an alarm at the exact specified date-time. Otherwise the "schedule" methods are enough, letting the system choose the proper nearest date-time to trigger the alarm accordingly to some system factors.

Answer (score 2):

Google states: "*(when your app) requires precisely-timed actions*". Your use case is "*to schedule update weather data (…) send notification to user*". While this might be user-facing, it doesn't seem to require to be precisely on a certain time. I would guess your app doesn't qualify.

The methods requiring the additional permission are currently: `setExact()`, `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` and `setAlarmClock()`. Repeating alarms will always be inexact. Seems like getting processing weather data and device sensors is something repetitive anyway.

Answer (score -1):

From what you've mentioned, you're talking about user-facing features.

A hypothetical example of the opposite would be Facebook forcing synchronization of user data at some specific time. That would be bad because it's preferable not to force a schedule on those types of things as it doesn't matter whether it happens at a specific time or a minute later when system resources are not used by some other service.

Also, "should" means it's a recommendation. Facebook *can* do the above, but it would be a less optimal solution. It's best to leave control over those kinds of services to Android as it would likely do a better job at distributing resources and preventing lag. So in other words, you not listening to their recommendation won't get your app removed from the app store or something like that.

Also, the paragraph you quoted from the second link, has a link to [examples of acceptable use cases](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#exact-acceptable-use-cases), and it mentions alarm apps. This is likely why your question was downvoted.