# Android permission SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM required with USE_EXACT_ALARM for alarm app?

Tags: android, android-alarms

My [app](https://github.com/WrichikBasu/ShakeAlarmClock), already published on Google Play and currently targetting Android 12, is an alarm clock app. In the latest release, I have used the `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` permission and also handled checking and requesting this permission at runtime, as required.

Upon checking the behaviour change for Android 13, I found that there is a new permission `USE_EXACT_ALARM` which has very restrictive use cases as listed [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#exact-acceptable-use-cases). My app is an alarm clock app, and hence it qualifies to use this permission. (An advantage of using this permission is that the system automatically grants it, and it cannot be revoked by the user.)

I added this permission to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and removed the `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` permission. However, Android Studio gives me a lint warning on the method `alarmManager.setAlarmClock(...)`:

[image]

This is what the warning reads:

> Setting Exact alarms with `setAlarmClock` requires the `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` permission or power exemption from user; it is intended for applications where the user knowingly schedules actions to happen at a precise time such as alarms, clocks, calendars, etc. Check out the javadoc on this permission to make sure your use case is valid.

The [Android Developers website](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#exact-permission-declare) says that I have the option to declare *either* of the permissions based on my use case. However, Android lint tells me that I should declare `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` irrespective of whether I have already declared `USE_EXACT_ALARM`.

What should I do? Follow the website and suppress lint?

Comment: I have exactly same problem, did you find an answer?

Comment: @AVEbrahimi I decided to use only `USE_EXACT_ALARM` by following the website. It _seems_ that this supersedes the `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` permission.

Comment: Did you test on Android 12? On Android 12 if there is no SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM it will crash while settings alarms

Comment: for android 12 and 13 please refer to my solution [her](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72183560/2828651).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer's actually buried in the [`USE_EXACT_ALARM` permission's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission?hl=en#USE_EXACT_ALARM):

> Apps need to target `API Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU` or above to be able to request this permission. Note that **only one** of `USE_EXACT_ALARM` or `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` should be requested on a device. **If your app is already using `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` on older SDKs but need `USE_EXACT_ALARM` on SDK 33 and above, then `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` should be declared with a max-sdk attribute**, like:
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"
>    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
> ```

So it's kind of a conditional thing - if you're on 33+, then `USE_EXACT_ALARM` will be available, and the other one won't be requested at all.

Comment: Ah, OK. So we need both, and specify the max SDK for the older one. Thanks!

Comment: solution is not working for android 13!